# putting the appname in a codenarc report title

Tags: grails, codenarc

just started with the codenarc plugin for grails - seems to be great!
But now I try to configure a dynamic report title like this:
"code quality report for ${appName}"

Unfortunately, it seems that the `appName` property is not available at the right time - I just get a null value.

Any ideas?

PS: using Grails 2.0.4 with ":codenarc:0.19"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appName` is by default bound in `BuildConfig.groovy` but is not available to the configuration closure for `codenarc`. I am yet to become cognizant of an absolute reasoning behind that behavior, unless anyone here throws some light on it. But you can very well read `application.properties` directly to get the appName as below:

```
codenarc.reports = {
    def props = new Properties()
    new File("application.properties").withInputStream {props.load(it)}

    MyHtmlReport('html') {
        outputFile = "${props['app.name']} - CodeNarc-Report.html"
        title = "${props['app.name']} - Sample Report"
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the reason is that it's not a config builder but a closure. THe solutions doesn't look great (having to re-read the props), but it works like a charm! Thanx